# Removing SQL Duplicated Fields based on HistoryID

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

I have a database with duplicate values.  Specifically SiteCode, LastName, FirstName, DateofService, Payer, BilledAmount, NetReceivable, and ContractualDiscount concatenate to form records that recur repeatedly throughout this table.

I'd like to remove all but one instance of these fields and am trying to do so by picking just one NetBilledHistoryID (which is a unique field for each record in the table).

Unfortunately, when I run this query, I still get the duplicated values.

How can I correct this so that my select query eliminates these duplicates?  Or, even better, should I be using a different query technique all together?

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Reports].[dbo].[NetBilledHistory] t1
WHERE EXISTS ( 
                SELECT 1 FROM [Reports].[dbo].[NetBilledHistory] AS t2
                WHERE t2.SiteCode = t1.SiteCode
                AND t2.LastName = t1.LastName
                AND t2.FirstName = t1.FirstName
                AND t2.DateofService = t1.DateofService
                AND t2.Payer = t1.Payer
                AND t2.BilledAmount = t1.BilledAmount
                AND t2.NetReceivable = t1.NetReceivable
                AND t2.ContractualDiscount = t1.ContractualDiscount
                AND t2.NetBilledHistoryID < t1.NetBilledHistoryID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that by using `CTE`:

```
WITH cte_query AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        partition by SiteCode, LastName, FirstName,
            DateofService, Payer, BilledAmount, NetReceivable,
            ContractualDiscount
        order by NetBilledHistoryID) AS RowNum, *
  FROM [Reports].[dbo].[NetBilledHistory]
)

SELECT * FROM cte_query where RowNum = 1;
```

adjust as needed to fit your purpose for columns, etc.

Comment: btw, this is for sql 2005 and above